# How to expand all drill down rows while loading a datatable, including the hidden rows

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm working on creating a datatable that has a drill down (row details) sub datatable as per the requirement. I was able to create the sub datatable when using drill down (row details) approach, but finding it hard to expand all of these rows that have drill down associated while loading the table. Here is the code I have and it works and expands all drill down rows on the current paginated table., but when clicking on the next pagination (number or page), the rows shows as expand (you know you can see the 'minus' (close) icon image) but no sub datatable. As far as I understood, its because, when I'm trying to simulate a click on the 'img' attribute associated for a drill down row, its being applied successfully for the current rows in the current page, but for the rest, which are not in the dom, the script says that the sub datatable is undefined. Any ideas or suggestions around this would help me a lot..

Below is the code snippet -

Table HTML source code -

```
    <table id="mastertable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" aria-describedby="sample-table-2_info">
        <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <!-- <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Domain: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 255px;"></th> -->
                <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Domain: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 25%;">Project Name</th>
                <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Price: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 10%;">Status</th>
                <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Clicks: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 10%;">Start Date</th>
                <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Clicks: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 10%;">End Date</th>
                <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Clicks: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 10%;">FCS Date</th>
                <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Clicks: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 10%;">Project Phase</th>
                <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Clicks: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 15%;">Defects</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">

    <tr>


                <td class=" ">

                <img src="/tester/theme/v_1_0/app-images/details_open.png"  masterProject="master-ROORKELA"/>

                    <a href="/tester/dashboard/project/abc">ROORKELA </a> <font color="black">(System Project)</font>

// THIS IS THE SUB DATATABLE HIDDEN IN DIV AND THE ID OF THE DIV IS STORED IN THE IMG ATTRIBUTE ABOVE UNDER THE 'masterProject' attribute - [masterProject="master-ROORKELA"]

                    <div class="hide" id="master-ROORKELA">

                                <table id="subProjects-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover subTable" aria-describedby="sample-table-2_info">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr role="row">
                                            <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 255px;">Project Name</th>
                                            <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 186px;">Status</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 203px;">Start Date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 203px;">End Date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 203px;">Targetted Date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 203px;">Project Phase</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-480 sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 203px;">Defects</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>


                                    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">

                                    <tr>

                                                <td class=" " style="width: 26%;text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;">

                                                    <a href="/tester/dashboard/project/abc">Sirish</a>

                                                </td>
                                                <td class="hidden-480 " style="width: 10%;">
                                                    <span class="label label-sm label-warning">Minor Impact</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class=" " style="width: 10%;">Feb 12 2013</td>
                                                <td class="hidden-480 " style="width: 10%;">Nov 12 2013</td>
                                                <td class=" " style="width: 10%;">Jan 16 2014</td>
                                                <td class=" " style="width: 10%;">EFT</td>
                                                <td class=" " style="width: 15%;">
                                                <a href="/tester/dashboard/project/abc/defects.html" class="modal-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#displayDefects">22 defects</a>

                                            </tr>


                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                    </div>

                </td>
                <td class="hidden-480 ">
                    <span class="label label-sm label-warning">Minor Impact</span>
                </td>
                <td class=" ">Feb 12 2013</td>
                <td class="hidden-480 ">Nov 12 2013</td>
                <td class=" ">Jan 16 2014</td>
                <td class=" ">TESTING</td>
                <td class=" "><a href="/tester/dashboard/project/abc/defects.html" class="modal-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#displayDefects">22 defects</a>
            </tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>
```

Defining the initial table -

```
  var oTable = $('#mastertable').dataTable( {

                "aLengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, 100 , -1], [5,10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                "iDisplayLength" : 10,
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                             {"sWidth": "25%", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                             {"sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
                             {"sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
                             {"sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
                             {"sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 4 ] },
                             {"sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 5 ] },
                             {"sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 6 ] },

                             {"sClass": "align-left" , "aTargets": [ 0,1,4, 2,3,5,6] }              
                         ],
                "sDom": '<"row"<"col-sm-4"l><"col-sm-6"f><"col-sm-1 saveas_div"T><"col-sm-1 filtering_div"C>r>t<"row"<"col-sm-6"i><"col-sm-6"p>>',

                "oTableTools": {
                    "aButtons": [
                               {
                                   "sExtends": 'csv',
                                 "sButtonText":'Export as CSV',
                                   "mColumns":"visible"
                               }
                           ]
                },
            "aoColumns": [
              { "bSortable": true },
              null, null, null,null, null, 
              { "bSortable": true }
            ],
            "bStateSave": true,
             "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
                 localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_'+window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData) );
             },
             "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
                 return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('DataTables_'+window.location.pathname) );
             }

            });
```

Associating click events on the 'img' attributes in the table -

```
 oTable.$('td').each( function () {

                    $(this).on('click','img', function () {
                        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
                        if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
                        {
                            /* This row is already open - close it */
                            this.src = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/theme/v_1_0/app-images/details_open.png";
                            oTable.fnClose( nTr );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            /* Open this row */
                            this.src = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/theme/v_1_0/app-images/details_close.png";

                            var masterProject = $(this).attr("masterProject");

                            var html = $("#"+masterProject).html();

                            console.log(html); // THIS IS WHERE I SEE AS UNDEFINED FOR HIDDEN TR ELEMENTS WHICH ARE HIDDEN DURING PAGINATION

                            oTable.fnOpen(nTr, html, 'details');

                            }
                    } );    

                    $(this).find('img').trigger('click'); // THIS IS WHERE I"M SIMULATING CLICK EVENT TO EXPAND ALL ROWS WHILE LOADING PAGE BY DEFAULT.

            });
```

I tried using the - fnDrawCallback method to simulate the click events, but its giving me weird results, meaning rows are expanded on alternate pages like 1,3,5 but on consecutive pages.

Sorry for this monologue, as am just trying to explain the detail of the problem.

Please pass on your valuable suggestions or solutions..

Many thanks,
Sirish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added functionality on button to collapse all and expand all child rows. that will work with pagination, search and

```
    <script>
    function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full CallStack:</td>'+
            '<td style="text-align:left;">'+d.call_stack+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var isCollapse = 1;
    var visited_cehck = 0;
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "aaData": $Json_data,
   "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "col1", "mData": "col1" },
        { "sTitle": "col2",  "mData": "col2" },      
        { "sTitle": "col3",  "mData": "col3" },
        { "sTitle": "col4",  "mData": "col4" },
        { "sTitle": "col5",   "mData": "col5" },
        {
        "class":          'details-control',
        "orderable":      false,
        "data":           null,
        "defaultContent": ''
        }
    ]
    } );


 //This function gets the length of the row and collapse and 
//expend all the rows depending on the current state of the row:    
    function collapse_exand_rows(){
        var table_length = $('#example tbody tr').length;
        for (var i = 0; i < table_length; i++) {
            var tr = $('.details-control').parents('tr').eq(i);
            var row = table.row( tr );
            if(!tr.hasClass('visited_child') || visited_cehck != 1){
                if ( isCollapse === 1 ) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }   
            }
        }
    }

//This event handles click for on each child row to show and hide rows.
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
        visited_cehck = 1;
        tr.addClass('visited_child');
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );

//This event handles navigation bar below the report to show and hide all the visible rows
    $('.dataTables_paginate').bind('click', '.details-control', function(event) {   
        if(visited_cehck === 1){
            return false;
        }
        collapse_exand_rows();
    });

//This event handles collapse expand button click to show and hide all the visible rows
    $('#collapse_expand').on('click', function(event) {
        visited_cehck = 0;
        if(isCollapse === 1){
            $('#collapse_expand').text('Collapse All');
            isCollapse = 0; 
        }
        else{
            $('#collapse_expand').text('Expand All');
            isCollapse = 1;
        }
        collapse_exand_rows();
    });

//This event handles dropdown to show and hide all the visible rows
    $('select').on('change', function (event) {
        collapse_exand_rows();  
    });

    $("thead > tr", '#example').click(function(event) {
        collapse_exand_rows();  
    })

    $(':input').change(function(event) {
        collapse_exand_rows();  
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @ShahidSiddique Do you have any idea about [How to create jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991927/how-to-create-jquery-datatable-drill-down-rows) Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
var table_length = $("#mastertable tr").length;
var paginate_button = $('.paginate_button');
for(var i = 0; i< table_length; i++){
    var tr = $('#mastertable tbody td.details-control').eq(i).parents('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);
     row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
}
```

if you have pagination :

```
isCollapse === 0
paginate_button.on('click',function(){
    table_length = $("#example tr").length;
    if ( isCollapse === 1 ) {
          for(var i = 0; i< table_length; i++){
                var tr = $('#example tbody td.details-control').eq(i).parents('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
             }
       }
    else {
        // Open this row
        for(var i = 0; i< table_length; i++){
             var tr = $('#example tbody td.details-control').eq(i).parents('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    }       
        });
```

Comment: If you are using pagination then: